# Is there a way to do 'not equal to' in elementtree xpath expression?

Tags: python, elementtree

Looking for a way to do 'not equal to' in `ElementTree` with an Xpath expression.  Everything i've tried ends up with "invalid predicate" SyntaxError.  Has anyone had any luck with this?

Here's an example of what i'm trying to do:

`worker.findall("ws:Related_Person[ws:Operation!='REMOVE']", ns)`

That produces the SyntaxError, but if i use:

`worker.findall("ws:Related_Person[ws:Operation='REMOVE']", ns)`

...it works fine.  Unfortunately i need 'not equals' in this situation, as there are several good values and only 1 value i want to ignore.

Is this possible with `ElementTree` or do i have to switch libraries to `lxml` for basic not equals comparisons?   The data source changed their output on me and i'd rather not have to rewrite the codebase using another xml library just to handle a `!=` if i can avoid it.

Comment: no you can't do this with `ElementTree`. from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) "This module provides limited support for XPath expressions for locating elements in a tree"